# Creating a plist if one doesn't exist

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, plist

I've got a bit of code that imports settings into my app from an email, but it only works if the `plist` it imports the settings into already exists.

This is the code I'm using currently to import the settings and write to the plist.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
if (url){

        NSDictionary *openedDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];

        // get paths from root direcory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        // get documents path
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // get the path to our Data/plist file
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
        NSDictionary *originalDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

        NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = [originalDictionary mutableCopy];
        for (NSString *key in openedDictionary) {
            if (!newDictionary[key]) {
                newDictionary[key] = openedDictionary[key];
            }
        }

        [newDictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error while deleting: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But what I need to do is create that `Data.plist` if it's not there, or alternatively rename the plist that's emailed to `Data.plist` and store it provided there isn't already a `Data.plist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *defaultManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) 
   {
        // rename the file
    }
    else 
    {
        //create empty file
    }
```

this is how you can create empty `plist` file

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];

//you can create file in any path in app sandbox, for example I'm creating in document dir.
NSString *FilePathWithName = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; 
FilePathWithName = [FilePathWithName stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"name.plist"];
[dict writeToFile:FilePathWithName atomically:YES];
```

and **for renaming** what you can do is, **you can load the `.plist/.property` file (that you want to rename) as dictionary and write that Dictionary with new name (write plist as above) and delete the `.plist/.property` file.**

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would create the property list through code and retrieve data from it as well.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"plist.plist"]; NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) 
{
    path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"plist.plist"] ];
}




NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSMutableDictionary *data;

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) 
{
            data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
}
else
{
    // If the file doesn’t exist, create an empty dictionary
    data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

//To insert the data into the plist
int value = 5;
[data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value] forKey:@"value"];
[data writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
[data release];

// To retrieve the data from the plist
NSMutableDictionary *savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
int value1;
value1 = [[savedStock objectForKey:@"value"] intValue];
NSLog(@"%i",value1);
[savedStock release];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSFileManager *defaultManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
        //Do stuff with path
    }
    else {
        //Write a plist to the path
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works to check if there's anything there or now, but how do I go about creating the empty plist/renaming my .properties file?

Comment: I don't know about renaming your .properties file, but writing a dictionary to a file will create your plist. There is a big long page by apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html